# Key Parameter Error in CouchDB

Tags: json, curl, couchdb

I am new to couchdb. I have written a simple mapreduce view.

```
simplemap:
{
     "map":"function(doc) { emit(doc.name, doc.marks); }",
     "reduce": "function(keys,values) { return sum(values);}"
}
```

I executed it using the following command:

```
curl http://localhost:5984/student/_design/student1/_view/simplemap
```

The query executed. However, when I am executing the below command, I am receiving an error.

```
curl http://localhost:5984/student/_design/student1/_view/simplemap?key="Kruti"&group=true
```

My map is emitting the following values.

```
{"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"2c1e1641694b8eeed8f88088ea0033b0","key":"Charupriya","value":90},
{"id":"d763d3f8d41aff068eb2bff9470007a7","key":"Charupriya","value":94},
{"id":"2c1e1641694b8eeed8f88088ea002556","key":"Kruti","value":96},
{"id":"d763d3f8d41aff068eb2bff94700037d","key":"Kruti","value":92},
{"id":"2c1e1641694b8eeed8f88088ea002be9","key":"Neha","value":98},
{"id":"d763d3f8d41aff068eb2bff94700053b","key":"Neha","value":98}
]}
```

Can anyone please tell me, why my query with key parameter is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and reading few links, I found that as key is string value it has to be given as

```
key=\"Kruti\"
```

By doing this, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your reduce function isn't running, here is what I get as a result from `simplemap` when I query it:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":null,"value":235}
]}
```

A reduce result should just return one value, unless you call it with the `group` parameter. So somehow you're not doing the reduce, and you cant use `group=true` for views that are not reduced.

ps: If you want to sum values use the built in _sum function, it's much faster than everything you can write yourself.

Comment: I think the reduce is working. Hence only one key value pair has been given as output. The error was because of key parameter. Since the key is string value, it has to be given in the following format:     key=\"Kruti\" and it worked.